# How do I extract sections (multiple sections per page, multiple pages) of a word document/pdf/image as separate images/word documents/pdfs?

Tags: c#, java, c++, pdf, image

Here's the basic problem: I have about 10,000 word documents that contain blocks of data. Each block is numbered and also has an accompanying image. I need to somehow store these individual blocks to a db as images (text would be great, but read note below), without the numbering.

I can go through and have typists mark the beginning and ends of the blocks using a ###QUESTIONSTART###, ###QUESTIONEND### or whatever. **I am trying to take that document, convert it to a big image, look for those tags, extract the part in between the tags as an image and then move on to the next block.**

I've been looking at some APIs and I think I can definitely crop the images once I figure out how to get the coordinates of each start/end marker. Any suggestions? I'd hate to write a pixel by pixel matcher that has to go O(no of blocks * n^2)

NOTE: These blocks contain complex equations/math type stuff hence the images. I don't have the $$ to get 1000 typists trained in TeX and retype the whole deal. OCR doesn't cut it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand all your question, but in my impression, [Tika](http://tika.apache.org/) can help you.

Comment: Tika currently does only text/mime-type parsing. Not sure if I could use it for spitting out images.

Answer (score 0):

If you can have typists add block marks to 10,000 documents, why can't the typists

- Open the Word document
- Copy the image from the Word document
- Paste the image into Paint
- Save the image to their disk?

You can come up with a image naming scheme that makes sense to you and your typists.

Then you can collect the images from the disk drives with a program and load them into your database.